# Understing .bst language

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am trying to modify this piece of `.bst` file:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #0 'numtrunc :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
  numnames #1 > 
    { #1 'numtrunc := }
    {}
  if$
  { namesleft #0 > }
  { s nameptr
    "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$
    't :=
    nameptr #1 >
      {
    nameptr #1 - numtrunc = 
      { 
        #1 'namesleft :=
        "others" 't :=
      }
      {}
    if$

        namesleft #1 >
          { ", " * t * }
          {
            numnames #1 >
              { "," * }
              'skip$
            if$
            s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
              { 't := }
              { pop$ }
            if$
            t "others" =
              {
                " {et~al.}" *
              }
              { " \& " * t * }
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
      't
    if$
    nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
    namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
  }
  while$
}
```

I am not familiar with this language. I want to print the bibliography only with one name, so everything should be written as:

```
author1 et al,
author2 et al,
etc.
```

Comment: For the general question, a good reference: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: Perhaps the question header should be "Understanding ..."?